# How to use Neural Network to map keywords?

Tags: php, machine-learning, neural-network, php-ml

I am new to machine learning and neural network. I have a situation where, for house providing, we study the cases of a candidate and of a housing in order to predict the answer of the candidate. I have been given an exemple looking like this :

Input1:

```
['male', '+60yo', 'health reasons', 'domestic abuse reasons','asked with elevator', 'already denied without elevator', ...]
```

Input2:

```
['60m²', 'city_name', 'without elevator']
```

Hidden layers:

```
['+60yo', 'health reasons'], ['asked with elevator'], ['already denied without elevator'], [etc.]
```

Output:

```
'Denied without elevator'
```

---

So, I'd like to use ANN to simulate this situation, but the tools I'm using works only with numbers data, not key words.
I'm actually doing it on php with the PHP-ML library and think of using the Multilayer Perceptron Classifier method.

Does somebody know something that could help me?

PS:
Since I don't know yet how to do such a thing, I've been training only with numerical data leading to a label, and for this here is how it looks:

```
// $labels is an array with all the unique possible output
$labels = ['a','b','c'];
$mlp = new MLPClassifier(4, [2], $labels);
$mlp->train(
    $samples = [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
    $targets = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c']
);
$mlp->predict([[1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]]);
// return ['b', 'c'];
```

Comment: What did you try ?(post code)

Comment: Well for the moment my colleague still didn't send me the file with the data so I don't even know yet how it will really look like. For the moment I'm doing research in order to be prepared at the time. (I'm a trainee)